# How to close websocket from server using spring

Tags: spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I am using spring framework and spring websocket 4.0.6.

I am work with web-socket and I need to find way to close them from server.

Is there way do do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Once you've got a reference to a User session (probably a SockJSSession if you're using sockjs), you can manually close the session:

```
session.close();
```

See the [javadoc for reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/WebSocketSession.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I currently only use STOMP over WS. Not using SockJS. But will have a look at it too. You have any sample code or link to it?

Comment: See the javadoc Link I gave, it's actually the WebSocketSession class, so it works as well in your case. Remember each client can have several websocket sessions.